# Recursive Query on Graph ends with error "could not write to tuplestore temporary file" in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query, postgresql-11

I ended up with a table storing a network topology as follows:

```
create table topology.network_graph(
node_from_id varchar(50) not null,
node_to_id varchar(50) not null
PRIMARY KEY (node_from_id, node_to_id)
);
```

The expected output data in something like this, where all the sub-graphs starting from the node "A" are listed:

[image]

Now I try to find the paths between the nodes, starting at a specific node using this query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE network_nodes AS (
    select 
    node_from_id,       
    node_to_id,
    0 as hop_count,
    ,ARRAY[node_from_id::varchar(50), node_to_id::varchar(50)] AS "path"
    from topology.network_graph
    where  node_from_id = '_9EB23E6C4C824441BB5F75616DEB8DA7' --Set this node as the starting element
    
    union
    
    select  
    nn.node_from_id,        
    ng.node_to_id,
    nn.hop_count + 1 as hop_count,
    , (nn."path" || ARRAY[ng.node_to_id])::varchar(50)[]  AS "path" 
    from topology.network_graph as ng
    inner join network_nodes as nn
    on ng.node_from_id = nn.node_to_id
    and ng.node_to_id != ALL(nn."path")
)
select node_from_id, node_to_id, hop_count, "path"
from network_nodes 
order by node_from_id, node_to_id, hop_count  ;
```

The query runs several minutes before throwing the error:

> could not write to tuplestore temporary file: No space left on device
> recursive query postgresql

The topology.network_graph has 2148 records and during the query execution the base/pgsql_tmp directory grows bis some GBs. It seems I have an infinite loop.

Can someone find what could be wrong?

Comment: Why are you choosing to use archaic join syntax instead of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: would you mind adding the table schema expected output & some sample data to your question please.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: sorry if this is anoying, I just got the basic ideas from some blog entries and have not pay attention to that.

Comment: the screenshot doesn't add anything useful. please refer to this document on tips for asking good sql questions

Comment: @HaleemurAli: sorry, now I got your point and edited the question again. BTW: where is the link for the document you mentioned?

Comment: it was my mistake. I forgot to add the link. Here's the link on how to ask good sql questions on SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Can you please explain the typo in this line?  `on n.node_from_id = nn.node_to_id`  You do not have a table aliased as `n`.  Are you referencing `ng` or `nn` on the left hand side of that condition?

Comment: I commented the "order by" out and now it works.